# GTK - Python Treeview Selecting A Row Programmatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, treeview, gtk, gtk3

I have a GTK3 GUI (with Python 3.7). There is a treeview on the GUI and sorting, filtering is used. I need to select a row by using code. It works when sorting is not used. It selects wrong row when sorting is used by clicking on column header buttons.

What is the solution for this?

Here is the simplified code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file('test1.glade')
window1 = builder.get_object('window1')
treeview1 = builder.get_object('treeview1')

class Signals:
    def on_window1_destroy(self, widget):
        Gtk.main_quit()

file_data = [[True, "a", 1],
             [True, "b - select this", 2],
             [True, "c", 3],
             [True, "d", 4]]

treestore1 = Gtk.TreeStore(bool, str, int)
iter1 = treestore1.append(None, file_data[0])
iter2 = treestore1.append(None, file_data[1])
iter3 = treestore1.append(None, file_data[2])
iter4 = treestore1.append(None, file_data[3])

#treeview1.set_model(treestore1)
treemodelfilter1 = treestore1.filter_new()
treemodelfilter1.set_visible_column(0)
treemodelsort1 = Gtk.TreeModelSort.new_with_model(treemodelfilter1)
treeview1.set_model(treemodelsort1)

for i, column_title in enumerate(["Column1", "Column2"]):
    renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
    column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(column_title, renderer, text=i+1)
    column.set_sort_column_id(i+1)
    treeview1.append_column(column)

treeview1.get_column(1).clicked()
treeview1.get_column(1).clicked()
#treeview1.get_selection().select_iter(iter2)
path = treestore1.get_path(iter2)
treeview1.get_selection().select_path(path)

builder.connect_signals(Signals())
window1.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Here is the Glade designer GUI file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="default_width">300</property>
    <property name="default_height">300</property>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkTreeView" id="treeview1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <child internal-child="selection">
          <object class="GtkTreeSelection"/>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Answer (score 1):

For anybody else coming here, the actual problem is that it doesn't turn out well to mix `iters` or `paths` between different models of the same Treeview. If you get a path of the filtered store, don't apply it to the sorted store, etc, etc. There are ways around this, but they are very complicated. They deserve a whole article explaining the nuances. In practice, if you need operate on the path of a store, get your info from **that same** store.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem by using the following code:

```
treeview1.get_column(1).clicked()     # Existing code in the question
treemodelsort1.set_sort_column_id(1, Gtk.SortType.ASCENDING)  # Solution
path = treestore1.get_path(iter2)     # Existing code in the question
```

Treestore has to be sorted first and after that path could be get correctly.

**EDIT:** This code works but according to @theGtknerd's answer, it is not the exact solution for the problem. Currently I have no knowledge about the exact solution and details of the @theGtknerd's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using treemodelfilter1 to sort the treeview. To get the exact tree path to the selection after selecting, you can use treemodelfilter1  instead of treestore1. This should work.

```
    path = treemodelfilter1.get_path(iter2)
```